# React Native ViewPagerAndroid setPage doesn't call onPageSelected callback

Tags: react-native

Simple dragging calls onPageSelected callback as expected. But changing page with setPage doesn't call this callback. Is this expected behaviour?

On iOS dragging and scrollTo method both calls onMomentumScrollEnd callback

react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.50.3
react: 16.1.0